# Are the Men In Black movies an example of spiritual growth?

Tags: analysis, men-in-black-3, men-in-black, men-in-black-2

Are these movies an example of--or a type of playbook for--spiritual growth?

- The first movie forces J (Will Smith) to shed the reality of People; to let go of the world he knew.
- The second movie forces J to shed the physical wants of Love; to let Love go--with it's smiles & frowns.
- And the third film, forces J to understand the truth; to not demonize others; for others have always and will always be there for you; regardless of your understanding of the current world.

If these were spirit enhancing films, is the goal of each (and all other like movies) to ultimately reach a state of 'Griffin' (where in the third film, he chooses what world he lives in; and due to believing in it with his entire body, he goes there, and brings those who are under his arms).

Answer (score 2):

I would feel that you are right. I haven't thought about it before, but what you said does make sense.

> [Definition of spiritual growth](http://timeforchange.org/definition-of-spiritual-growth-what-is-spiritual-growth):
>
> There is no official and exact definition of spiritual growth. We -
> and many others - use personal spiritual growth as synonyms for other
> terms like e.g. personal spiritual development, to develop higher
> awareness or to develop higher consciousness.

As stated above, it depends on someone's view of the true meaning of `spiritual growth`. My opinion on the matter is that since J made this decision and advanced as a person not only physically, but mentally, he changed his life from then on. Like I said, it just depends on the person.